# How do I make a horizontal single row high low close chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I am using MS excel 2013.

I would be grateful if someone could point me in the direction of a function or workaround in excel that will help me to build a small single line chart to be included in a report.

I would like a horizontal line representing a range of the lowest and highest figures from the last twelves months, with a point on that line representing the current position of the figure.

I would also like this chart to always be the same length. I would imagine this part is easy though as I would calculate percentages, then use them to drive the chart.

I am trying to create something like this:
[image: example of a chart I am trying to create]

The closest I came up with is the `stock` `high-low-close` chart. This allows me to achieve what I want for multiple data points. But not for a single row of data.

Here's an example of a `stock` `high-low-close` (this is the closest I have got):
[image: this is the closest I have got]

Here is an example of some figures I might want to show in this chart.

My example data is a comma separated table with text defined in square brackets.

```
[high],[low],[current]
1000,10,600
```

EDIT: Thanks to CharlieRB for making my question more pointed and fixing my title.

Comment: New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add example of the data, what you have tried so far and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Thank you for your comments CharlieRB. I am not expecting anyone to do my work for me in the slightest. This is why I did not initially include my data. I was just asking for guidance. I apologise if I did not explain my question sufficiently.

Comment: I have now edited my question to include some data.

Comment: Please add image (mspaint is your friend) representing wanted result (+printscreen of source data table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [bullet charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_graph).

[image]

There are two excellent tutorials from [Charley Kyd](http://www.exceluser.com/excel_dashboards/bullet-graph.htm) and [Jon Peltier](http://peltiertech.com/bullet-charts-in-excel/) about how to create them in Excel.

The techniques are slightly different but both use stacked horizontal bars and error bars for the "current" marker.

If you want just a thin line and a marker, you can create an XY scatter chart with two series, one for the line, and one for the marker.

[image]

Comment: I used your answer using the high and low as 100% and 0%. Then calculating the current figure as a percentage as the middle marker. Thank you for your help!